# How to pass Object value to other component in Angular4?

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to pass object value to another component while navigating from one component to another without showing data in URL.

I m trying something like this, when clicking  it will redirect to secondComponent. in URL i will show /15  but i also i want to pass object to secondcomponent that should not visiable on url.

Could someone please tell me how to pass object at the time of navigation and how to capture it on second component

Is it possible to sent obj value inside  [routerLink]="15 **passThisObj**"

Eg:

```
{ path: ':id', component: SecondComponent }


<a [routerLink]="15 passThisObj1">Edit</a>
<a [routerLink]="16 passThisObj2">Edit</a>
<a [routerLink]="17 passThisObj3">Edit</a>
<a [routerLink]="18 passThisObj4">Edit</a>
<a [routerLink]="19 passThisObj5">Edit</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, But i am looking without using input, output and i want to pass obj inside <a>  @RameshRajendran is it possible to pass values inside routerLink ?

Comment: Go with cookies or localStorage or sessionStorage

Comment: its like table with five row each row will have <a> and i need to pass row id along with routing inside <a>

Comment: Question, why is it important that it does not show in the URL?

Comment: because client don't like to show those in url :(

Comment: Use event emittors

Comment: can't user services here ? pass the data to service and then inject the service into component to share data. just as an alternative for what you are trying to do.

Comment: If they are not related, use a shared service :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is not technically possible with angular, the only way to pass data as part of a `routerLink` is by modifying the URL. However if the data to be passed is related to the route parameter in a one-to-one relationship, you can store those objects in an object in a service, and in your component (the one being routed to) use that service to query the data object based on the route parameter.